# Spring rest vs standard Rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

In spring doc, I can get following explanations for the difference of the spring mvc and spring rest.
**Spring REST architecture is also based on Spring MVC, slightly making the difference on the View part. Traditional Spring MVC relies on the View technology to render the model data, the Spring REST architecture also does the same, except that the model object is set directly into the HTTP response, which the @ResponseBody converts into JSON/XML automatically. The output of a RESTful web service has to be a JSON or an XML, a standard format that could be easily handled across different consumer application platforms.**

But in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer.
It has a couple of feactures except for the json response like the rest will use the HTTP PUT/DELETE/POST method to manipulate resource.

I was wondering if below spring controller can be treated as a restful service. I have used @RestController to return json response, but did not use any other rest features.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = RequestAction.LOADLIST, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<Employee>  list(@RequestBody Employee bo) {
        System.out.println(bo);
        return employeeList;

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = RequestAction.LOAD, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Employee getEmployee(
            @RequestBody Employee input) {
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            if (employee.getId().equals(input.getId())) {
                return employee;
            }
        }
        return input;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = RequestAction.ADD, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee bo) {
        System.out.println(bo);
        return bo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = RequestAction.UPDATE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee bo) {
        System.out.println(bo);
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            if (employee.getId().equals(bo.getId())) {
                employee.setName(bo.getName());
                return employee;
            }
        }
        return bo;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're confusing *a design pattern* (REST) with *tools* (Spring) that can be used to implement REST or many other patterns. You can certainly implement REST in Spring, but I'd note that your example isn't a good one--you're using a bunch of custom URIs to describe actions instead of using HTTP verbs (e.g., `updateEmployee` should be `@PutMapping("/{id}")`).

Comment: You can implement RESTFUL APIs using Spring, To make your controller restful, You can follow REST model, You can refer https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Answer (score 0):

Your example script is not REST because it change the url for each task, and use always POST verb. Spring REST use different HTTP verbs (GET, POST, DELETE) to differentiate the action. A few times sharing the same url.

Example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
    @GetMapping
    public List<User> index() {...}

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public User show(...) {...}

    @PostMapping
    public User create(...) {...}

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public User update(...) {...}

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void delete(...) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not following the conventionals of a REST API (e.g. GET for retrieval, POST for create, PUT for full update, PATCH for partial update, etc.), but it does not mean, that you can't. As others stated above, you might just got confused with the term. REST is a protocol and it has lots of conventionals for service usages, which if you follow, you can say that your service is REST or RESTful.
This page is the simple best source of tutoring you in this area:
https://restfulapi.net
More importantly this, when we are considering your example: https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

I also check it sometimes.